# My git commits disappeared when I aborted an operation

Tags: git, version-control, refactoring

I was doing some refactoring on a codebase, so I made a lot of `WIP` commits in the repo. after it was finished, I ran `git rebase -i devel` and tagged all the commits except last as `squash`, but then I thought that I shouldn't squash them right now, so I tried aborting the operation by quitting the editor (nvim) with `:q!`. But it looks like some of the squash operations were actually performed.
Current state:

- The repository is one commit ahead of `devel`, with some staged and some unstaged changes
- The state of the working tree is very close to the original state(`devel`)

How can I get the repo back to how it was before I initiated the `rebase` operation?

Comment: Run `git reflog` to find out at which commit it was before the rebase.

Answer (score 0):

If the git status mentions the rebase as still being in progress, you should be able (since Git 2.12) to type:

```
git rebase --quit
```

Then check if your working tree is in the correct state.